# What format for high resolution textile designs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, patterns, file-format

I've completed several prints for a designer on Illustrator and sent them to her in press quality PDF format. She asked me to convert them to PNG or JPG, but I found this makes the artwork lose a lot of quality. What is the best high resolution format (besides PDF) to send to her for printing?

Thanks :)

Comment: There is no suitable answer without knowing more details. If the file is CMYK you cannot use PNG, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, neither PNG nor JPG are suitable for "high-quality printing". If those are the formats she's asking for, send those.

If you need a raster format for printing, TIFF may be suitable.

Really, this is a difficult question to answer without seeing samples. There's really no reason a PNG or JPG would "lose quality" with an initial save.

Answer (score 1):

Do what she asks.  She wants PNG or JPEG.

In Illustrator click *File > Export > Export As*

Choose the format

When the dialog appears, increase the resolution until you think it's good enough.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use anything else than PDF for your print layouts. What can be a problem is that if your PDF will contain too many objects and because of that printer's software is having difficulties to reproduce it. In that case just try to flatten objects inside your PDF file (or in Illustrator, Corel or whatever you are using to prepare graphic) and then in the end export it as PDF. And I very highly recommend to use PDF/X-1a on PDF/X-4 standart for export options as this is made specially for better print information delivery with your design.